# pause my API endpoint until an event happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, kafka-consumer-api, event-listener

Im currently trying to divide up a monolith application into micro 
services, mostly for practice and as a past time. I group all of the endpoint that called a specific 3rd party into one micro service. and when ever those endpoints are called I send the results over to a kafka broker.

Now I have another micro service that is meant to have endpoints read from kafka. Now when I call that endpoint it creates a Kafka consumer that is meant to listen for a message and when received execute some trivial code.  The problem here is that the endpoint is completely skipping my await and just closing up the endpoint.

The expected result would be:
1. Call endpoint A
2. Endpoint Listens to kafka for a message
3. We call endpoint B that pushes messages to kafka
4. Messages are listened by the first endpoint 
5. Some data manipulation occurs.
6. I get my results

For reference this is my endpoint A

```
 // Retrive the overall margin for all of the accounts
    app.use(route.get('/amount', async (ctx) => {

      // Saves the actual parsed valued for the kafka messages consumed.
      let parsedMargin

      // Array that keeps track of all the individual bot margins
      let totalMarginArray = []

      // Keeps the vaue of the actual sum of margins from all the bots
      let totalMargin
      // Initialise the kafka consumer
      consumer = new Consumer(client,[{topic: 'margin', partition: 0, fromOffset:'earliest'}],{autoCommit: false} );
      consumer.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log(message)
        // Parse the value consumed from kafka 
        parsedMargin = JSON.parse(message.value)
        // Push the margin from the parsed value above  
        totalMarginArray.push(parsedMargin.margin)

        if(message.offset == (message.highWaterOffset-1)){
            consumer.close(true, async (err, message) =>{
            console.log("consumer has been closed..")
          })
        }
      })

      let today = new Date()
      let date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

      if(totalMarginArray.length!=0){
        // Add up the margin from each of the bots
        totalMargin = totalMarginArray.reduce(( a , b ) => a + b)
        //Check currentMargin
        let currentMargin = await checkMargin([totalMargin, date])

        // Insert Margin into DB
        if (currentMargin == null){
          await insertMargin([totalMargin, date])
        }
      } else{
        // When there are no bots with margin set it to 0
        totalMargin = 0
      }


      // Response
      ctx.status = 200
      ctx.body =  { 
        data: totalMargin  
      }

  }))
```

Im happy to wait indefinitely for the messages. Not concerned with blocking the api here. Also endpoint A and B are from two differen APIs each from their own microservice

Comment: `consumer.on('message', (message) => {` is a callback, dump the rest of the code in there or use a promise

Comment: could you do a rough draft of how a promise would look like here?